# Regex for finding trigonometry function with variable

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have the string:

```
-15*sin(h)**2+121*sin(h)-216
```

I'm currently using

```py
input_text = re.findall(r"sin|cos|tan|\d|\w|\(|\)|\+|-|\*+", input_text.strip().lower())
```

to try to tokenize this string, but it returns the following:

```
['-', '1', '5', '*', 'sin', '(', 'h', ')', '**', '2', '+', '1', '2', '1', '*', 'sin', '(', 'h', ')', '-', '2', '1', '6']
```

Could someone help me modify my regex statement so I get

```
['sin(h)']
```

as a token instead of it being broken into

```
['sin', '(', 'h', ')']
```

On top of that could I use [a-zA-Z] so I can tokenize the trig functions for any letter? As in sin([a-zA-Z])

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `(`, `\w`, and `)` alternatives to the trig functions, make them part of that same match.

```
(?:sin|cos|tan)\(\w\)|\+|-|\*+
```

Comment: I'm getting unbalanced parenthesis when i try using this. Sorry I'm a noob at regex.

Comment: I had an extra `)` at the end left over from an earlier edit